# Migrate Project to TFS2018

Tags: tfs

I have two TFS servers - one running 2008 and the other running 2018.  I need to move one project (not all) from the TFS 2008 server to the new one.  I only need to migrate the source code but would like also maintain all version and checkin history.  Is there an upgrade process or utility that can achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to  maintain all version and check-in history.  The only way is upgrading TFS server 2008 with database.

**Direct upgrade to Team Foundation Server 2018 Update 2 is supported from TFS 2012 and newer.** Since your TFS deployment is on TFS 2008, you will need to perform some interim steps before upgrading to TFS 2018 Update 2. Please see the chart below for more information.

[image]

If you want to change the hardware which is a restoration-based move, and you should never combine the two move types. First complete the hardware move, and then change the environment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/move-across-domains?view=tfs-2015v

***Would it be best to do the upgrade in-place before moving hardware/domain?***

You could do in place upgrade, or move to new hardware. If you're upgrading in place, consider doing a [dry run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/upgrade/pre-production?view=tfs-2017&viewFallbackFrom=tfs-2018) of your upgrade in a pre-production environment, and make sure the [system environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/requirements?view=tfs-2018) is meet.

***Are there any particular pitfalls I should be wary of?***

Before upgrade, you can read [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/upgrade/get-started?view=tfs-2018) first, and be sure you have full backup of your database.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to migrate from TFS 2008 to TFS 2018, at which point you can delete whatever projects you want from TFS 2018. That's going to be the easiest way to do it. Besides there being no really solid work item migration tools, **everything** has changed significantly since TFS 2008, including things like APIs, work item layouts, fields, features, etc. You're looking at a miserable process to get data from 2008 to 2018 without signficant effort.

The TFS 2008 -> TFS 2018 upgrade process is going to be a [bit fiddly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs/server/upgrade/get-started), because you can't go directly from 2008 -> 2018, you'll have to go from 2008 to 2012, then 2012 to 2018. However, it's totally supported and is relatively painless, outside of having to do it in multiple steps.

Comment: Thanks for the information! So since I cannot upgrade the 2008 server itself, i first need to backup the TFS database, restore it on a temporary TFS 2008 server, and then upgrade to 2012 / 2018? And then finally move the upgraded database to the new server?