# Does TFS web interface support Test management in Internet explorer 11

Tags: testing, tfs

Does TFS 2008 support test management om Internet Explorer 11

Internet Explorer 11

Comment: I would doubt it since I'm not even sure if IE11 was released before TFS 2008 hit end of life

Answer (score 0):

TFS2008 is a very old server version and out of support for a long time( Released over 10 years).

Highly recommend you to move to a newly versioned TFS server. Detail process of the upgrade, you could take a look at my answer in this question: [Migrate Project to TFS2018](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51260649/migrate-project-to-tfs2018/51284527#51284527)

There is not any official document which declare this related info. After go through **Web portal supported browsers** of [Azure DevOps client compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/compatibility?view=azure-devops):

> To connect with the web portal, you can use the following browsers
>   with Azure DevOps Services and Azure DevOps on-premises. Edge,
>   Firefox, and Chrome automatically update themselves, so Azure DevOps
>   supports the most recent version.

[image]

Most of the Microsoft product support down-level compatibility, guess IE11 should be compatible with the web portal of TFS 2008. But not totally sure if  test management  also work properly. Better to double confirm this in your TFS environment.

Lastly, please upgrade your TFS 2008 to higher version which could get official support and some new features.