# Visual stduio 2010 and 2012 and 2013 connect to team server foundation 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, visual-studio-2013

I want to use team server foundation 2008 and have it connect to Visual Studio 2012 or Visual Studio 2013. 
I want to do this since I want to upgrade my visual studio 2010 .net web form applications to visual studio 2013.

Thus can you tell me if this is possible and what I can do to make this occur?

Also will I be able to still keep Visual studio 2010 connected to Team server 2008 and also have Visual Studio 2013 connect to Team server 2008 on my same workstation? Is there something I need to do so team server foundation will 2008 to both Visual studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2013 and potentially Visual Studio 2012 on the same workstation? If so, what would I need to do?

Comment: That answers my question. thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, visual studio 2012 and visual studio 2013 is **not compatible with TFS2008**. In other words, unlike visual studio 2010, you able not able to use them to connect TFS2008.

You could refer jessehouwing's blog which got all options documented on it: [Connect any version of Visual Studio to Azure DevOps or Azure DevOps Server](https://jessehouwing.net/azure-devops-connect-any-visual-studio-version/)

[image]

Besides, TFS2008 is a very old server version and already been out of support for a long time( Released over 10 years).

Highly recommend you to move to a newly versioned TFS server. Detail process of the upgrade, you could take a look at my answer in this question: [Migrate Project to TFS2018](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51260649/migrate-project-to-tfs2018/51284527#51284527)